# AppEngine Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.appengine.api.search.Index.add

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

Im using AppEngine SDK 1.7.0 in my webapp. Recently, errors was log as

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
com.google.appengine.api.search.Index.add([Lcom/google/appengine/api/search/Document;)
Lcom/google/appengine/api/search/AddResponse;
```

The error just happened recently, it doesn't have the problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe they(google) have changed Index.add() to Index.put(Document ...docs), regards to the latest version of API doc.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/Index

Comment: are the webapps developed w/ previous SDK version still affected?

Comment: if your old web app is still running with previous SDK version, it might be ok, but that is something I cannot guarantee. To make it clear, better to raise your concern to GAE developer forum.

Answer (score 2):

AddResponse was deprecated and removed from the SDK.
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes

You need to remove all reference to that class and then redeploy.